# Output arrays within an array grouped by a common index

Tags: php, arrays, indexing, grouping

I have an array, seen below. My desired output is to group by store, and then concatenate (I think?) all of the related quantities and denominations into those arrays. I've shown what the desired output would be.

CURRENT ARRAY

```
Array
(
    [denomination] => Array
        (
            [0] => 25
            [1] => 50
            [2] => 100
            [3] => 200
        )

    [quantity] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 1
            [2] => 2
            [3] => 4
        )

    [store] => Array
        (
            [0] => candy store
            [1] => candy store
            [2] => book store
            [3] => candy store
        )

)
```

DESIRED OUTPUT

```
Array
(
    [candy store] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [denomination] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 25
                            [1] => 50
                            [2] => 200
                        )

                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [quantity] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 1
                            [1] => 1
                            [2] => 4
                        )
                )

        )

    [book store] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [denomination] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 100
                        )

                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [quantity] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 2
                        )
                )
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = array();
foreach ($array['store'] as $index => $type) {
  $result[$type]['denomination'][] = $array['demoniation'][$index];
  $result[$type]['quantity'][] = $array['quantity'][$index];
}
```

This is not exactly, what you specified as "desired output", but I don't see a reason, why one should put the `denomination`- and `quantity`-arrays into additional arrays.

However, if this has any reason, you can get it similar

```
$result = array();
foreach ($array['store'] as $index => $type) {
  $result[$type][0]['denomination'][] = $array['demoniation'][$index];
  $result[$type][1]['quantity'][] = $array['quantity'][$index];
}
```